# How to add a new CSS class to a Drupal7 <form>?

Tags: 7

Hello I created the following form iterating for each node:

```
...
$render['my_list'][] = drupal_get_form('shop_form_item_'.$node->nid, $node->nid);
...
```

$render will output the form on the page. The forms will be shop-form-item-20, shop-form-item-21 etc...

```
function shop_forms($form_id, $args) {
  $forms = array();
      if(strpos($form_id, 'shop_form_item_') === 0) {
        $forms[$form_id] = array('callback' => 'shop_form',);
      }
  return $forms;
}

function shop_form($form, &$form_state, $nid) {
  $form = array();

    $form['my-item-name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#value' => isset($node->title) ? $node->title : '',

  );


  return $form;
}
```

Now I need to add a class: `<form method="post" action="" class="cart">`
How do I insert it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to add it to the [`#attributes`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes) key of the `$form` array:

```
function shop_form($form, &$form_state, $nid) {
  $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'cart'; // Classes are added to an array and internally converted to a single string by Drupal later on

  $form['my-item-name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#value' => isset($node->title) ? $node->title : '',
  );


  return $form;
}
```